# Products details in opencart didn't show in my store

Tags: php, opencart

I have an issue in open-cart.

I am trying to make some changes in code, so after I made some changes in file `latest.PHP`, i then get the following problem:

The details page for each product doesn't show for me.

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Check your PHP error log, or OpenCart's error log - that should give you an idea of what might be going wrong.

Comment: If you wish any help, first you should place your code here what are you have changed. then errors what you have received.

Comment: I just change word " Latest to New Products" .

Comment: Undefined offset: 3 in /var/www/html/upload/catalog/controller/extension/module/quickorder.php on line 11 >> I found this issue in error log